# Decode base64 to array of floats

Tags: sql, base64, amazon-athena, presto

I have a 768 length array of float values that have been tokenized and are stored in a string field in an Athena table.  I want to extract from that string the 768 original float values. In python, this works using numpy and then rounding to 6 significant places:

```
def decode_to_np_array(input_bytes):
    decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(input_bytes)
    return np.frombuffer(decoded_bytes, dtype=np.dtype('>f4')).round(6)
```

My SQL so far is:

```
select from_base64(tokens)
from data_embeddings
```

which returns:

```
3c 9f e7 cb 3d 97 e0 fa 3d a3 46 bf 3c 51 78 ...
```

of length 9,216 characters, which is 3,072 in length and works out to 4 X 768 base64 values.
What SQL function(s) can I use to get 768 float values from this?

I tried looking for some useful Athena functions but haven't found what works.

Edit: Here is an example I generated in python for an array of 3 values

The original bytes are:

```
vxCa5z03fqC9AA2w
```

In Python, I can decode these input_bytes to:

```
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(input_bytes)
print(decoded_bytes)
b'\xbf\x10\x9a\xe7=7~\xa0\xbd\x00\r\xb0'
```

In SQL, there is:

```
select from_base64('vxCa5z03fqC9AA2w')
bf 10 9a e7 3d 37 7e a0 bd 00 0d b0
```

Which is the same, python and SQL.

The final array output matches my original input, which is:

```
array([-0.5648636 ,  0.04479849, -0.03126305], dtype=float32)
```

So in the end, b'vxCa5z03fqC9AA2w' would transform to that array of 3 float32 values.

Comment: Please add sample encoded  base64 data (possibly not all 768 values).

Comment: Added example, thanks for prompting me to do so.

Comment: `SELECT from_ieee754_32(substr(from_base64('vxCa5z03fqC9AA2w'),1,4))` will give you the first value from the array, and you can iterate over it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

`SELECT transform(sequence(1, 3*4, 4), x -> from_ieee754_32(substr(from_base64('vxCa5z03fqC9AA2w'),x,4)))`

The long answer:

- `from_base64('vxCa5z03fqC9AA2w')` or the longer string in the table converts it back to bytes/binary
- `substr(B),1,4` extracts the 4 bytes from the first (or any other location) in the binary above `B`
- `from_ieee754_32(SB)` converts the 4 bytes above (`SB`) to float (here, -0.5648636)
- `sequence(1, 3*4, 4)` or any other length besides 3 generates an array of integers from 1 in steps of 4 (bytes) (here, [1,5,9])
- `transform(array(T), function(T, U))` transforms the input array to an output array with the above function (`from_ieee754_32...`)